# Oracle Dynamic 'SQL select' query record type

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

The dynamic request looks like this:

```
request := 'select * from ' || param_table_name || ' where ' || column_name_list;
```

Then I do:

```
open cur1 for request;
```

The exact type of record fetched via `cur1` isn't known until runtime, because it should impose no restrictions on whatever table this procedure is applied to. But then, how do I iterate through what the query returns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PL/SQL cursors cannot work with columns that aren't known a compile time.

To only way to work with fully dynamic queries in PL/SQL is by using the PL/SQL package `DBMS_SQL`.

**Update:**

Oracle has a comprehensive description of the [DBMS_SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm) package with many examples.

Comment: I know there is such a package. And that's all I know about it, unless you tell more :)

Comment: I've added a link to a description of the package.